# Accessing JS object value with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

So lets take this code:

```
    $('.show-popup').on('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(id);
        console.log(overlay_data[id]);
    });
```

I get this output:

```
28125 
undefined
```

If I hard code the value in, it outputs every time. But it does not work, if I pass the key via variable. How could I make this work?

Comment: Could you put an example where you can observe this behavior?

Comment: I don't have it online yet. But basically overlay_data is a JS object. I can access values no problem with hardcoded keys, but now with variable. What extra information would you need?

Comment: Ok, I am sorted. the data atribute had a trailing space in the HTML code. Thanks for trying to help! :)

Comment: `overlay_data[28125]` = `undefined` means that your `overlay_data` array does not have and element at the `28125` pos, can you provide what does `overlay_data` contain .

Comment: Hey @bRIMOsBor, i got is sorted. The problem was that I had trailing space in my attribute, and that is why I was getting the undefined error. Thank you :)